# How can I use an NSArray and NSArrayController with Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I have some code which needs to access a NSArray to work. I have a NSArray which I am using with Core Data and will have data in it, but I am unsure how to make my NSArrayController access the NSArray.

I can't just simply declare it in the Header file like this: `NSArray *objectArray;` because it does not know how or which `NSArray` to access. How exactly would I access the NSArray I am using with Core Data?

**My Header File:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface MyOutlineView : NSOutlineView {
    NSArrayController* objectArray;
}

@end
```

**My Implementation File:**

```
#import "MyOutlineView.h"

@implementation MyOutlineView

- (void) outlineView: (NSOutlineView *) aView
     willDisplayCell: (id) aCell
      forTableColumn: (NSTableColumn *)aColumn
                item: (id) anItem
{
    id rootObj = anItem;
    unsigned row = [aView rowForItem:anItem];

    [aCell setDrawsBackground: YES];

    while ([aView levelForRow:row] != 0) {
        row --;
        rootObj = [aView itemAtRow:row];
    }

    // The colours here are foul and ugly.  Use something else, for
    // God's sake!
    if( [objectArray indexOfObject:rootObj] % 2 )
        [aCell setBackgroundColor: [NSColor yellowColor]];
    else
        [aCell setBackgroundColor: [NSColor blueColor]];
}

@end
```

Comment: In what way are you using the NSArray with Core Data? Do you want to fetch Core Data objects into a NSArray object?

Comment: I am using the NSArray to store text which is in an Outline View. I have some code which will make the Root Object in the Outline View have a different Background color. But it needs to access the NSArray to figure out which is the Root Object.

Comment: What object holds the NSArray now? Do you have a NSArrayController in your Nib which controls the NSArray? That might make sense, this way other objects van bind to the NSArrayController.

Comment: An NSArray… to store text? Also, you know that entities can't have ordered collection properties, right? You have to create and execute a fetch request, and you'll need to provide the fetch request with sort descriptors if you want the objects in a non-random order.

Comment: Well It's Not Just Text, But thats not relevant. I do have an NSArrayController in my Nib file which controls the Array.

Comment: Then it's easy isn't it? Just let the code that needs to access the array talk to the NSArrayController object?

Comment: How would I do that? I tried an IBOutlet connecting to the NSArrayController but that gave me an error.

Comment: How would I let the code access the array talk to the NSArrayController object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a test app with IBOutlet connected to NSArrayController from Xib. In this test I have:

- started from Core Data application template;
- created Entity in data model with two attributes (string, int);

in Xib:

- Array Controller with managed object context, connected to Test_AppDelegate.managedObjectContext;
- TableView with cols connected to Array Controller's first and second attribute of arrangedObjects;
- Add and Remove buttons, connected to Array Controller's add: and remove: actions;
- Button "Show Count" and Label; -

in code (Test_AppDelegate.*):

- IBOutlet NSArrayController *ac; (connected in Xib from Test_AppDelegate.ac to Array Controller);
- IBOutlet NSTextField *nLabel; (connected in Xib to Label);
- (IBAction)showNum:(id)sender; (connected from "Show Count" button);
- code in action showNum:
  [nLabel setIntValue:[[ac arrangedObjects] count]];

I'm able to:

- Add/Remove objects to table view and controlled array;
- Access NSArrayController from code to get arrangedObjects array.

So binding IBOutlet from code to Xib's Array Controller and accessing its arrangedObjects should work.

Comment: I've Tried Using an IBOutlet to declare objectArray and link it to the NSArrayController. But I get an error saying 'Invalid Operands to binary %' on the line ' if( [objectArray indexOfObject:rootObj] % 2 ) ' because it is looking for an array not an array controller. How would I fix this? I have also updated the first post with all the code I am using.

Comment: I also read from where i got the code saying that I need to create a Selector. This is what they said, Assume self responds to a selector -objectArray which returns an array of the top-level objects displayed in the outline view, and in the right order.

Comment: There should be clear understanding that NSArrayController is a controller of array of objects but not an array itself. So to access objects from this controller you should use arrangedObjects property which 'Returns an array containing the receiver’s content objects arranged using arrangeObjects:' (from Apple documentation). These objects are arranged in compliance with sorter and filters of Array Controller and represented as a set of resulting managed objects (NSManagedObject). Each object contains values described in data model which can be accessed by keys with valueForKey: method.

Comment: So, in your case, [objectArray arrangedObjects] will return you an NSArray of all your objects. These objects will have NSManagedObject type (or inherited from it) and attributes can be accessed by [obj valueForKey:@"attributeNameFromDataModel"]. I'm not sure if anItem from your code returns correct type of object (NSManagedObject) and it can be used as indexOfObject: argument but at least you can get a whole set of objects from method I'd described and do your own search.

Comment: So what code do I need to change or add to the code in the first post?

Comment: To access objects you can use: `NSArray *objList = [objectArray arrangedObjects]; for (NSManagedObject *obj in objList) { NSNumber *attr1 = [obj valueForKey:@"attr1"]; <your logic>; }`. As I said I'm not sure if rootObj from your code is suitable for indexOfObject: function and I don't know the model of your objects but with this cycle you can access all the objects you have in your array and do your logic: finding item you want and making divisibility check on its value.

Comment: Thanks, Where in the code would I put `NSArray *objList = [objectArray arrangedObjects]; for (NSManagedObject *obj in objList) { NSNumber *attr1 = [obj valueForKey:@"attr1"]; <your logic>; }' ?

Comment: Your 'if' code accesses the array. The code I gave you do the same but in correct way assuming that objectArray is NSArrayController outlet, bounded from Nib. So you should use this approach to replace your `if( [objectArray indexOfObject:rootObj] % 2 )...`

Comment: Also, I pasted the code in and I got multiple errors and warnings. Here's a picture of what happened: http://snapplr.com/jvw9

Comment: What should I replace '<your logic>' with?

Answer (score 0):

I might not be getting this  - but can't you just create an initWithArray method?

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: Where do you create your MyOulineView - do you do it in code? If so then instead of using init override init and add your NSArray to the class.

Comment: No I created MyOutlineView in interface builder. Could you give some example code and what I need to add to my code?